# How can you save and share the data WITHOUT logging in

Tags: php, html, database, cookies, localhost

I  was looking at jsfiddle and shrib.com and the concept of saving and sharing your notes/code without logging in or making an account fascinated me a lot. I noticed they make a different URL for every new entry. So do they save the entry associated with the corresponding code in the database and send cookies to remember the computer or something(using php)? I obviously looked at the source code but obviously the website wouldn't be just HTML. I just wish to understand the concept that works behind. I'm uncertain what should I Google so I came here. My friend thinks there would be no cookies involved.

Thank you for your feedback in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They generate a unique ID which is embedded in the URL that you share; this is associated with the data in some back end storage so that it can be displayed when someone visits the URL.

Because of the requirement to share between users you can't use local storage or cookies, as this would only allow the original user to see the content, not share it.

Comment: Cool! And how do you create a new URL each time you click the SAME button?

Comment: There are lots of ways to generate "random" things, depending on the language that you're working with, e.g. PHP's uniqid().

Comment: Sweet! I think I will look at it :)

Comment: I finally looked at it and it was exactly what I wanted! Late for thumbs up but yea :)

Answer (score 1):

They probably do use a database of somesort to keep track of the URL's and its content. i doubt it has much to do with anything and that as soon as you visit the url the request is checked and the corresponing page is show to the user.

Also. they probably keep track of the last time visit/active and destroy the input after a certain time period altho im not sure about this

Answer (score 0):

Drawback of using cookies

- Limited with low amount of data nearly 4kb It will include your every
- HTTP request Will send same data again and again – it’s enough to
- slow down your web application Unencrypted  data over the internet
- (unless your entire web application is served over SSL)

You can use HTML5 Local storage for save data

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

For More detail about HTML5 local storage you can refer [Here](http://www.techyline.com/html5-storage-local-storage-for-web-application/)

Comment: This did answer my questions a bit. But what if I want to share this with someone? You can share a jsfiddle with a link (customized URL) but this is just my local storage.